# Slater Determinant in Python or Mathematica

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, computational-physics, software

Is there any way, maybe a library or package, to calculate Slater determinant in Python or Mathematica? What I want basically is this: I would define a single particle wavefunction and specify the number of fermions in the system, what I want is to determine the composite wavefunction, which of course, is given by Slater determinant. I want to accomplish this using Python or Mathematica (preferably python), using symbolic computation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.

Comment: are you using the Slater determinant to build atomic orbitals?

Comment: No. I am just want to construct wavefunction of N fermions, say e.g., trapped in a harmonic potential.

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica, there isn't much to it:

```
SlaterDeterminant[listOfψs_,listOfxs_]:=Simplify[Det[
                                           Table[
                                             ψ[x]
                                             ,{ψ,listOfψs},{x,listOfxs}]
                                           ]]
```

For functions of more than one variable, it helps if you define the wavefunctions in the format `ψ[{x_, y_}]` rather than `ψ[x_, y_]`. So, for example,

```
ψ1[{x_, y_}] := x + I y
ψ2[{x_, y_}] := x - I y

SlaterDeterminant[{ψ1, ψ2}, {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}]
```

will return $2 i (x_2 y_1 - x_1 y_2)$ as expected.

Comment: This is much better than my answer +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to give the code because it still has pedagogical value. Here's the Mathematica code:

```
n = 3;
Ψ = Table[Subscript[ψ, i], {i, 1, n}];
dummyVariables = Table[Subscript[i, j], {j, 1, n}];
positionVariables = Table[Subscript[x, j], {j, 1, n}];
iterators = Table[{dummyVariables[[j]], 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
ϵ = LeviCivitaTensor[n];
slater = Sum[
  Product[Ψ[[dummyVariables[[j]]]][
     positionVariables[[j]]], {j, 1, n}] ϵ[[
    Sequence @@ dummyVariables]],
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ iterators]
  ]
```

Slightly more readable version:
[image]

So how it works: eventually we want to compute
$$\Psi(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i_1,\cdots,i_n}\psi_{i_1}
(x_1)\times\dots\times\psi_{i_n}(x_n)\epsilon_{i_1,\dots i_n}$$
where $\epsilon$ is the [Levi-Civita tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol). This is also mentioned in Vadim's answer.

To implement this in code I define `iterators` as a list of the form $\{\{i_1,1,n\},\dots,\{i_n,1,n\}\}$ where each $i_j$ is a dummy variable to be summed over. Now I use a nice trick. Whenever `Sequence[a,b,c]` appears inside a function everything inside `Sequence` gets automatically treated as function arguments. So

```
f[Sequence@@{a,b,c}] == f[Sequence[a,b,c]] == f[a,b,c]
```

I use this to evaluate the sum over dummy variables:

```
Sum[x+y,Sequence@@{{x,1,n},{y,1,n}}] == Sum[x+y, {x,1,n}, {y,1,n}]
```

The product inside the sum evaluates to $$\psi_{i_1}
(x_1)\times\dots\times\psi_{i_n}(x_n)$$
so I hope that's enough info to decipher the rest of my code.

Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do with the slater determinant?

Comment: I've prettified the main code section, using [this userscript](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks that really useful actually

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use [the expression for the determinant in terms of Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n_%C3%97_n_matrices):
$$
\det(A) = \sum_{i_1, i_2, ...,i_n=1}^n\epsilon_{i_1...i_n}a_{1,i_1}...a_{n,i_n}
$$
Levi-civita symbol or all the possible permutations can be calculated in numpy: see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740966/levi-civita-tensor-in-numpy), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210142/get-all-permutations-of-a-numpy-array/41210450), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list), whereas $a_{k,i_k}$ above are to be replaced by $\psi_k(x_{i_k})$, and the whole divided by the normalization factor $\sqrt{n!}$

Since this is a symbolic determinant, in will not get any simpler than the general determinant expansion.

Comment: Thanks, Roger! Can you also point out how to implement this symbolically? What I want is this determinant as a function of $x_1,\, x_2, \cdots, x_n$.

Comment: I don't know how to do this symbolically. What I wanted to stress is this is the final symbolic form that you will get - there is no gain from using mathematica here.

Comment: Alright, Thank you!

Comment: @VincentThacker There is no factor in the definition of the determinant. However the SLater determinant will have to be normalized, indeed - by $\sqrt{n!}$. I added the correction.

Comment: @RogerVadim Ah, I see that you're using the single symbol definition for the determinant. I'm used to the one with two Levi-Civita symbols contracted over the matrix, without any explicit indices, which does have a factor of $1/n!$, because it is easier for manipulating tensors.